# Can't access my games after transferring game data to a new harddrive

Tags: ps3

I have a PS3 (80GB) not YLOD yet and I got a new one, the 500 GB and I plugged my 120 GB USB in to my old Playstation and downloaded all the data from it. Then I plugged it into my new PlayStation, and downloaded all the data onto the new one, but when I go to play my games none of them will show up. Please help, I cant play any of my Playstation games.

Comment: Make sure your signed into the same PSN account as you were using before.

Comment: already did......................

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the PS3 [Data Transfer Utility](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/transferutility.html). Data on your PS3's hard drive gets encrypted and can only be decrypted on that same physical machine. The Data Transfer Utility decrypts on your old machine, sends that data across to your new PS3 via an ethernet cable, where it is encrypted on the new console.